# Subprocess paste text with stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

why stdin is sending data while there is no communicate()

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
p=subprocess.Popen('runas /user:domain\user cmd',stdin=PIPE, 
universal_newlines=True)
```

and when adding the line

```
p.communicate('password')
```

nothing changes